# GlobalRouting Error in combining wireless networks and point to point connection

Tags: c++, networking, routes, wifi, ns-3

I am trying to create a network topology of n wireless networks and attach a single node to each of the wifi-ap nodes(as point to point connection) of all wireless networks.

I created an echo application to send datas between the single node(remote node) and one of the wifi nodes.
But I am getting an error as below when i try to run this code

**assert failed. cond="w_lsa", file=../src/internet/model/global-route-manager-impl.cc, line=809
terminate called without an active exception**

The propose topology is attached as image.[topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ak9C.png)

How to route the packets in this topology?

Here is the code.

```
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"
#include "ns3/point-to-point-module.h"
#include "ns3/wifi-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/csma-module.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/bridge-helper.h"
#include "ns3/netanim-module.h"
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace ns3;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  uint32_t nWifis = 2;
  uint32_t nStas = 2;
  bool sendIp = true;
  bool writeMobility = false;

  CommandLine cmd;
  cmd.AddValue ("nWifis", "Number of wifi networks", nWifis);
  cmd.AddValue ("nStas", "Number of stations per wifi network", nStas);
  cmd.AddValue ("SendIp", "Send Ipv4 or raw packets", sendIp);
  cmd.AddValue ("writeMobility", "Write mobility trace", writeMobility);
  cmd.Parse (argc, argv);

  NodeContainer backboneNodes;
  NetDeviceContainer backboneDevices;
  Ipv4InterfaceContainer backboneInterfaces;
  std::vector<NodeContainer> staNodes;
  std::vector<NetDeviceContainer> staDevices;
  std::vector<NetDeviceContainer> apDevices;
  std::vector<Ipv4InterfaceContainer> staInterfaces;
  std::vector<Ipv4InterfaceContainer> apInterfaces;

  InternetStackHelper stack;
  CsmaHelper csma;
  Ipv4AddressHelper ip;
  ip.SetBase ("192.168.0.0", "255.255.255.0");

  backboneNodes.Create (nWifis);
  stack.Install (backboneNodes);

  backboneDevices = csma.Install (backboneNodes);

  double wifiX = 0.0;

  YansWifiPhyHelper wifiPhy = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default ();
  wifiPhy.SetPcapDataLinkType (YansWifiPhyHelper::DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO); 

  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nWifis; ++i)
    {
      // calculate ssid for wifi subnetwork
      std::ostringstream oss;
      oss << "wifi-default-" << i;
      Ssid ssid = Ssid (oss.str ());

      NodeContainer remoteHost;
      remoteHost.Create(1);
      Ptr<Node> remote=remoteHost.Get(0);
      Ptr<Node> apnode=backboneNodes.Get(i);
      PointToPointHelper p2p;
      p2p.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue ("5Mbps"));
      p2p.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", StringValue ("2ms"));
      NetDeviceContainer p2pDevices = p2p.Install(apnode,remote);
      //setup remotenode
      stack.Install (remoteHost);

      // assign AP IP address to bridge, not wifi
      //Ipv4InterfaceContainer

      NodeContainer sta;
      NetDeviceContainer staDev;
      NetDeviceContainer apDev;
      Ipv4InterfaceContainer staInterface;
      Ipv4InterfaceContainer apInterface;
      Ipv4InterfaceContainer remoteInterface;
      MobilityHelper mobility;
      BridgeHelper bridge;
      WifiHelper wifi;
      WifiMacHelper wifiMac;
      YansWifiChannelHelper wifiChannel = YansWifiChannelHelper::Default ();
      wifiPhy.SetChannel (wifiChannel.Create ());

      sta.Create (nStas);
      mobility.SetPositionAllocator ("ns3::GridPositionAllocator",
                                     "MinX", DoubleValue (wifiX),
                                     "MinY", DoubleValue (0.0),
                                     "DeltaX", DoubleValue (5.0),
                                     "DeltaY", DoubleValue (5.0),
                                     "GridWidth", UintegerValue (1),
                                     "LayoutType", StringValue ("RowFirst"));


      // setup the AP.
      mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
      mobility.Install (remoteHost);
      mobility.Install (backboneNodes.Get (i));
      wifiMac.SetType ("ns3::ApWifiMac",
                       "Ssid", SsidValue (ssid));
      apDev = wifi.Install (wifiPhy, wifiMac, backboneNodes.Get (i));

      NetDeviceContainer bridgeDev;
      bridgeDev = bridge.Install (backboneNodes.Get (i), NetDeviceContainer (apDev, backboneDevices.Get (i)));

      // assign AP IP address to bridge, not wifi
      apInterface = ip.Assign (bridgeDev);
      remoteInterface = ip.Assign (p2pDevices);

      // setup the STAs
      stack.Install (sta);
      mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
      mobility.Install (sta);
      wifiMac.SetType ("ns3::StaWifiMac",
                       "Ssid", SsidValue (ssid),
                       "ActiveProbing", BooleanValue (false));
      staDev = wifi.Install (wifiPhy, wifiMac, sta);
      staInterface = ip.Assign (staDev);

      //creating udp applications

      UdpEchoServerHelper echoServer (9);

      ApplicationContainer serverApps = echoServer.Install(remoteHost.Get(0));
      serverApps.Start (Seconds (1.0));
      serverApps.Stop (Seconds (10.0));

      UdpEchoClientHelper echoClient (remoteInterface.GetAddress(1), 9);
      echoClient.SetAttribute ("MaxPackets", UintegerValue (1));
      echoClient.SetAttribute ("Interval", TimeValue (Seconds (1.0)));
      echoClient.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue (1024));

      ApplicationContainer clientApps = echoClient.Install(sta.Get(0));
      clientApps.Start (Seconds (2.0));
      clientApps.Stop (Seconds (10.0));

      // save everything in containers.
      staNodes.push_back (sta);
      apDevices.push_back (apDev);
      apInterfaces.push_back (apInterface);
      staDevices.push_back (staDev);
      staInterfaces.push_back (staInterface);

      wifiX += 20.0;
    }
    Ipv4GlobalRoutingHelper::PopulateRoutingTables ();

 /* Address dest;
  std::string protocol;
  if (sendIp)
    {
      dest = InetSocketAddress (staInterfaces[1].GetAddress (1), 1025);
      protocol = "ns3::UdpSocketFactory";
    }
  else
    {
      PacketSocketAddress tmp;
      tmp.SetSingleDevice (staDevices[0].Get (0)->GetIfIndex ());
      tmp.SetPhysicalAddress (staDevices[1].Get (0)->GetAddress ());
      tmp.SetProtocol (0x807);
      dest = tmp;
      protocol = "ns3::PacketSocketFactory";
    }

  OnOffHelper onoff = OnOffHelper (protocol, dest);
  onoff.SetConstantRate (DataRate ("500kb/s"));
  ApplicationContainer apps = onoff.Install (staNodes[0].Get (0));
  apps.Start (Seconds (0.5));
  apps.Stop (Seconds (3.0));

  wifiPhy.EnablePcap ("wifi-wired-bridging", apDevices[0]);
  wifiPhy.EnablePcap ("wifi-wired-bridging", apDevices[1]);*/

  if (writeMobility)
    {
      AsciiTraceHelper ascii;
      MobilityHelper::EnableAsciiAll (ascii.CreateFileStream ("wifi-wired-bridging.mob"));
    }

  AnimationInterface anim("edgecomp2.xml");
  Simulator::Stop (Seconds (5.0));
  Simulator::Run ();
  Simulator::Destroy ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem before but you could check this out here as follows.
[Global Routing problem with wifi infrastructure mode](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ns-3-users/wifi$20global$20routing/ns-3-users/Z9K1YrEmbcI/MrP2k47HAQAJ)

> GlobalRouting does NOT work with Wi-Fi